# How to restrict Google Form responses to logged in users?

Tags: google-app-engine, gmail, google-forms

I want to find a way to automatically find out who responded to my form (I am using Forms for quizzing and surveying students).

Is there any way to disallow the form from being filled out unless the user is logged in?

Given they are logged in, can I somehow get their Google username or Gmail address automatically through a script?

In addition, if they are logged in, can I make sure that they can only edit their own response, and not submit multiple ones? Right now, editing your response is only possible if you remember the link to your personal response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe everything is handled by the google form. In the top part of the form there is an option to make sure that the person who is answering is logged. And it's in the same place that there is the option to collect the username
[image: username login required in google form]

Comment: That's funny. [My Settings](http://i.imgur.com/Kwo6HD6.png) only have the third of the three options! Any idea why that could be?

Comment: my bad this is only available on enterprise account. Unfortunately you can't control the users so easily without this feature. I believe the only solution you've got left is to send to your users a prefilled url with a field reflecting a unique ID. When submited, the form will only record answers given with a valid unique ID

Comment: Right. I got the same idea, but it's much less convenient and much more error prone. Can you update your answer so I can mark it as correct? Maybe with a link regarding the Google enterprise details?